# java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\slask\isu.dsv

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, eclemma

When I am using code coverage in my application using EclEmma. It shows a
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\slask\isu.dsv` error, due to which Junit test is not done. Can you please help me out?

Comment: It seems pretty clear the file is not there. What is your question?

Comment: Could you show the code?

Comment: Please post whole stack trace, so we can see what and why is trying to access `C:\slask\isu.dsv`. Now it is not clear if it is related to `EclEmma` or your code.

Comment: Isn't it obvious? You don't have a file at `C:\slask\isu.dsv`.

Answer (score 0):

There could be two possible reasons:

1. A file with the specified **pathname does not exist**.
2. A file with the specified pathname does exist but is **inaccessible** for some reason (*requested writing for a read-only file, or permissions don’t allow accessing the file*)

Thanks.

Comment: That I also known. I am asking how can i resolve it. Can you suggest me how to get .DSV file

Comment: If possible please post the snippet with the stack trace. I would suggest you to to create a dsv(delimiter separated file of your own with the same name under that directory and then try running it) see, if that could help in getting rid of the exception, you can check the contents of dsv later. 
More on dsv file : https://datatypes.net/microsoft-office-excel-file-types

Answer (score 0):

Some points which needs to be checked

1. Check for the foldername , filename , directory name if this kind of exception appears (any kind spelling errors).
2. File you are checking for doesn't exists
3. In java file path should contain double backslash which may not be pointed out incase you are using a normal text editor for writing the code.